# Record data that comes through a certain port?

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 4, and it's running Raspbian OS (very similar to Debian). I was wondering if there was some way you could record any data that comes into or goes out of a certain port. Is there some command that's built-in, or one you could install with apt-get? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing tcpdump and using that?

```
sudo apt-get install tcpdump
```

Then check which interfaces are available with

```
tcpdump -D
```

Then check what's going on in the interface you require with

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 port 80
```

wlan0 being the name of the interface.

more info here:
https://geektechstuff.com/2020/02/15/tcpdump-raspberry-pi/

To record the data, redirect the output to a file by suffixing the command with `> name_of_output_file.txt`

For example:

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 port 80 >> tcpdump_log.txt
```